# Using a Lambda Expression Over a Dictionary<string, List<object>> in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<EquipmentRow>> TableRows { get; set; }
```

EquipmentRow class:

```
public class EquipmentRow
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public bool New { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create/filter a structurally same Dictionary as the previous one which only contains a list of items in which property `New` is equal to `true`.
How to achieve that by using a Lambda Expression?
For example:

`var newLocationDevices = locationDevices.Where(x => x.Value.Where())` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply using this code:

```
var newLocationDevices = locationDevices
    .ToDictionary(
        o => o.Key,
        o => o.Value.Where(i => i.New).ToList()
    );
```

Comment: 'KeyValuePair<string, List<EquipmentRow>>' does not contain a definition for 'New'

Comment: @DomagojHamzic I had a typo which I've just fixed it. `i=>i.New` instead of 'o.New'

Comment: Will it filter Key value elements where `New = false;`?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar As I understood the problem, only the inner list is needed to be filtered, not the outer one. Otherwise, another `Where` is needed just as you've mentioned.

Comment: What if inner list contains single element and it is `New=false`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter dictionary using [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) clause and check `bool` value using [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0),

```
var result = locationDevices
      .Where(x => x.Value.Any(x => x.New)) //Filter existing dictionary
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Where(y => y.New).ToList()); //Create new Dictionary.
```

Comment: thanks, also correct answer but I can not mark >1 answer as correct :(

Comment: @DomagojHamzic But you can do a +1

Comment: this is slightly different the accepted answer, keys that would have an empty list are not going to be present in the dictionary in this version.